# i'm tring to update stock table by 1 with laravel decrement() bt it subtract 7 every time. please find out my problem here is my code

Tags: laravel

i'm trying to update stock table by 1 with laravel decrement() bt it subtract 7 every time. please find out my problem here is my code.

```
 public function updateStockD(Request $request)
    {

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
        $pid =  $request->product_id;
        $stock_quantity = $request->stock_quantity;

        $data = array();

        $data['product_id'] = $request->product_id;

        $data['stock_quantity'] = $request->stock_quantity;

        $data['purchase_price'] = $request->purchase_price;

        $data['stock_created_date'] = date('Y-m-d');

        $data['stock_created_time'] = date('H:i:s');

        $data['stock_created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;

        DB::table('stock_d')->insert($data);
        DB::table('stock')->where('product_id',$pid)->decrement('stock_quantity', 1);

        Session::put('message', 'Product quantity added successfully!');

        return Redirect::to('/stock_d');
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you are not calling this method 7 times when doing the request or are you sure you are not doing 7 requests by calling every time this method (related to for loops, if you are using any)?

Comment: yes, i'm sure. i solve the problem. there are same product id seven times in my database. thats why it decrease 7 times. thanks for your response.